# ¿Cómo saber que números son divisibles entre 5 apartir de una matriz?

Tags: java, matrices, bucles, fórmulas-de-matriz

Me he quedado atorado en esta parte, no sé en que parte colocarlo y les agradecería mucho que me puedan ayudar. Aun no domino bien los vectores y realmente me confundo, mucho aun estoy tratando de entender como funcionan gracias. Este es mi código:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] vector = new int[100];//iniciamos el vector y su tamaño.
            for (int i = 1; i < vector.length; i++)//Creamos un ciclo for para su llenado.
            {
                vector[i] = (int)(Math.random()*50);//El llenado solo sera hasta el numero 50.
                if(i%5==0)
                {
                    for (int D5 = 1; D5 < vector.length; D5++)//Creamos un ciclo for para imprimir los numeros divisibles entre 5.
                    {
                        System.out.print(vector[D5] + " ");
                        System.out.print("");
                        if(i==42)
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
                for (int i = 1; i < vector.length; i++)//Creamos un ciclo for para imprimir los numeros guardados.
                {
                    System.out.print(vector[i] + " ");
                    System.out.print("");
                    if(i==42)
                        break;

                }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: deerías quitar los números mágicos y convertirlos en constantes

Answer (score 1):

**EDITADO**
corregi un grave error de logica...
agrege un poco de comentarios

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [] vector = new int[100];//iniciamos el vector y su tamaño.
    for(int i = 0;i < vector.length;i++){//
        vector[i] = (int)(Math.random()*50);//El llenado solo sera hasta el numero 50.
    }

    //En los vectores el conteo de la posicion empieza por el 0.
    //asi que: 1 = var[0], 2 = var[1], 2 = var[2].. asi sucesibamente

    //[int D5 = 4] por eso se inicializar la primera varible con 4 que enrrealidad es 5
    //[D5 < vector.length] comprobacion del bucle..
    //[D5 = D5 + 5] aumentamos el valor de 'D5' en 5 que es el valor que sigue divicible entre 5.
    for(int D5 = 4;D5 < vector.length;D5 = D5 + 5){
        System.out.println("pos: "+(D5 + 1)+" = "+vector[D5]);//como dije antes en posicion empieza de 0 asi que aumentamos en 1 
                                                            ////para que sea comprecible en forma estandar 
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega una breve explicación, al menos de porque este código es mejor del que se incluye en la pregunta.